# Selecting (n-1)D array from (n)D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Lets take a 3D array as an example. Or a cube for easier visualizing.

I want to select all the faces of that cube. And I would like to generalize this to arbitrary dimensions.

I'd also like to then add/remove faces to the cube(cuboid), and the generalization to arbitrary dimensions.

I know that for every fixed number of dimensions you can do `array[:,:,0], array[-1,:,:]` I'd like to know how to generalize to arbitrary dimensions and how to easily iterate over all faces.

Comment: In addition to Bas's answer, a common idiom in `numpy` of access to an arbitrary axis (e.g. `somefunc(somearray, axis=n)`) is to use `swapaxes` to switch the specified axis with the first axis in the array, and then operate on the first axis of the "swapped" result.  `swapaxes` makes a view, so no extra memory is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a face:

```
def get_face(M, dim, front_side):
    if front_side:
        side = 0
    else:
        side = -1
    index = tuple(side if i == dim else slice(None) for i in range(M.ndim))
    return M[index]
```

To add a face (untested):

```
def add_face(M, new_face, dim, front_side):
    #assume sizes match up correctly
    if front_side:
        return np.concatenate((new_face, M), dim)
    else:
        return np.concatenate((M, new_face), dim)
```

To remove a face:

```
def remove_face(M, dim, front_side):
    if front_side:
        dim_slice = slice(1, None)
    else:
        dim_slice = slice(None, -1)
    index = tuple(dim_slice if i == dim else slice(None) for i in range(M.ndim))
    return M[index]
```

Iterate over all faces:

```
def iter_faces(M):
    for dim in range(M.ndim):
        for front_side in (True, False):
            yield get_face(M, dim, front_side)
```

Some quick tests:

```
In [18]: M = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
In [19]: for face in iter_faces(M): print face
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[[18 19 20]
 [21 22 23]
 [24 25 26]]
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [18 19 20]]
[[ 6  7  8]
 [15 16 17]
 [24 25 26]]
[[ 0  3  6]
 [ 9 12 15]
 [18 21 24]]
[[ 2  5  8]
 [11 14 17]
 [20 23 26]]
```